# PHP Apache site error: failed opening required 'C:/xampp/htdocs/tutorial_php/Übung1/seite1.php'

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I am absolute beginner trying to get my first PHP script working on the localhost server.

I wrote some lines of code for it and saved it in the `C:/xampp/htdocs` folder.
After that step I wanted to load my site in my browser. The problem is, now I get this error message:

```
Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required 'C:/xampp/htdocs/tutorial_php/Übung1/seite1.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in Unknown on line 0
```

I read something about it, tried to set another permission, but nothing worked so far. Could you please help me?

Comment: Rename c:\xampp\htdocs and create a new, empty htdocs directory. You don't need the Xampp junk.

Comment: Any particular reason you use accented characters? `Ü`

Answer (score 2):

try the following on your cmd line:

php -S localhost:8888 -t public